# Custom PDO fetch function that works in a while loop

Tags: php, pdo

If this works..

```
$stmt = DB::$db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
while ($r = $stmt->fetch()) { print_r($r); }
```

Is there any way possible to get something like this to work?

```
function fetch() {
    $stmt = DB::$db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
while ($r = fetch()) { print_r($r); }
```

**UPDATE**

Or maybe if it's in a class it can work by using some sort of class iterator extension/implementation?

```
class User {
    public static function fetch() {
        $stmt = DB::$db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }
}
while ($r = User::fetch()) { print_r($r); }
```

**SOLUTION**

Well I did end up finding a working solution, but the accepted answer which uses a generator is probably the better way to go.

```
class User {
    private static $stmt;
    public static function fetch() {
        if (static::$stmt === null) {
            static::$stmt = DB::$db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
        }
        return static::$stmt->fetch();
    }
}
while ($r = User::fetch()) { print_r($r); }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php

Comment: your solution is extremely clumsy and error prone

Comment: I'm sure it is which is why I said I'd recommend the accepted answer over that solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would do it:

```
function fetch() {
    $stmt = DB::$db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) { yield $row; }
}
foreach (fetch() as $r) { print_r($r); }
```

Notes:

- It will only do the query once.
- The `yield` is php 5.5+.
- Use a `foreach` on your `fetch()` mini function.

The reason your initial attempt would not work, is the action just keeps looping indefinitely. Each call to your original `fetch()` its doing the query ***each call***, and thus returning the first result. This will make the `while` just go on and on.

Comment: Good example of generators!

Comment: I was really hoping to get it working with a while loop ran outside of the function. If I use a foreach then even this will work `function fetch() { return DB::$db->query('SELECT * FROM users'); }`

Comment: @Rick this answer DOES show you how to use while outside of the function

Comment: Well the title does say "in while loop".. Sorry if that was confusing.. I'm also updating the question by adding a version that uses a class. Perhaps some sort of class iterator extension/implementation can be used to make it work..

Comment: Oh well. I thought it actually is better to use the while and the generator, instead of just return it all. Despite the foreach. But... PDO, and all that. Its already pretty optimized.

Comment: No this is good! I probably will use this if it is not possible with the while loop. Going to give it a little more time to try and figure it our or see if any other suggestions pop up.

Comment: @Rick you are being unreasonable

Comment: I guess with this... the `while` is *inside* the `fetch()`, instead of outside. However, given that PHP returns objects by reference... and PDO's built in ability to iterate over rows from a `query` method... any optimization would be minimal (and it would just be better to go with fewer lines of code, than more =p)

Answer (score 2):

if you don't mid foreach instead of while

```
function fetch() {
    return DB::$db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
}
foreach (fetch() as $r) { print_r($r); }
```

Comment: This is just simply elegant.